# rails admin - Rendering a table inside a model show action

Tags: rails-admin

By default, rails_admin shows the :name or :title of an associated model list.

Is there a way to render a table similar to the one shown in 'list' action of the associated model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render anything you want with the formatted value block inside a field, a few examples:

```
rails_admin do
  show do
    # Rendering a json with a gem
    field :parsed_json do
      formatted_value do
        Json2table::get_html_table(value).html_safe
      end
    end

    # Building html tags inside the block
    field :classification do
      formatted_value do
        view = bindings[:view]
        ticket = bindings[:object]

        if view
          view.content_tag(:div, ticket.classification_name, {class: "alert #{value} ticket-alert"})
        else
          ''
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can also override the partial a field uses, to keep your viewing logic outside of the rails admin logic.

```
  config.model MyModel do
    edit do
      field :my_field do
        partial 'my_partial'
      end
    end
  end
```

And you'd put your partial path would be
app/views/rails_admin/main/_my_partial.html.erb

Comment: I understand everything is possible... just wanna know if there is a built in way to render it, like active admin and afministrate let you

Comment: There is not, you can check all the possible fields https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/tree/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types There is no table field built in